# How to remove variable characters in a column?

Tags: r

I am attempting to remove an appended "s.#" from a column in a data frame:

```
Species <- c("Dogs.1","Dogs.2","Dogs.3","Cats.1","Cats.2","Cats.3")
Breed <- c("Great Dane","Beagle","Beagle","Bengal","Tabby","Siamese")

names(Species) <- "Species"
names(Breed) <- "Breed"

pets <- as.data.frame(cbind(Species,Breed))
```

This produces the following data frame:

```
  Species      Breed
1  Dogs.1 Great Dane
2  Dogs.2     Beagle
3  Dogs.3     Beagle
4  Cats.1     Bengal
5  Cats.2      Tabby
6  Cats.3    Siamese
```

I'd like the output to look more like this:

```
  Species  Breed
1  Dog     Great Dane
2  Dog     Beagle
3  Dog     Beagle
4  Cat     Bengal
5  Cat     Tabby
6  Cat     Siamese
```

Is there a way of manipulating the Species column to take out the ".#"?

Comment: Do you need something specific to `data.table`? Otherwise, you might want to remove that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` here.  The patten below will remove a dot followed by one or more digits, occurring as the very last thing in the `Species` text.  I also remove an optional letter `s` which might (or might not) occur before the dot.

```
pets$Species <- sub("s?\\.\\d+$", "", pets$Species)
pets

  Species      Breed
1     Dog Great Dane
2     Dog     Beagle
3     Dog     Beagle
4     Cat     Bengal
5     Cat     Tabby
6     Cat     Siamese
```

### Demo

Comment: @Devin Answer updated.  You didn't mention the `s`, so I didn't cover that initially.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** To remove `s` too from Species column use following.

```
sub("s\\..*","",pets$Species)
```

To cover small and capital `sS` too use following.

```
sub("[Ss]\\..*","",pets$Species)
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
sub("\\..*","",pets$Species)
```

Or if Species column always have `.digits` then use following.

```
sub("\\.[0-9]+","",pets$Species)
```

In case you want to save the output in data frame's column itself use following then.

```
pets$Species <- sub("\\..*","",pets$Species)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(pets$Species, "^.*(?=s)")
[1] "Dog" "Dog" "Dog" "Cat" "Cat" "Cat"
```

I often find that when a dataframe is in long format and strings are formatted as something.# or something_#, that the # appended at the end can hold valuable information that can be used for grouping, faceting, stats, and/or data visualization down the road. I'm not sure if that is your case, however, but here is a way to pull the two bits of information apart to retain the appended information.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
new_pets <- pets %>%
    separate(col = Species, into = c("type", "owner"), sep = "\\.") %>%
    mutate(type = str_extract(type, "^.*(?=s)"))

new_pets
#   type owner      Breed
# 1  Dog     1 Great Dane
# 2  Dog     2     Beagle
# 3  Dog     3     Beagle
# 4  Cat     1     Bengal
# 5  Cat     2      Tabby
# 6  Cat     3    Siamese
```

Comment: you could use `sep="s?\\."` and then you wouldn't need the `mutate` line

Comment: Clever, I hadn’t thought of that.